# Interactive alternative to dot?

Tags: graph, visualization, graphviz, interactive

From time to time I need to visualize dependencies/dependent structures. For example function calls, data structures etc.

For relatively small graphs [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) `dot` is a good match. The input format of `dot` is easy to generate and it produces good layouts.

But sometimes the graph contains too many vertices and dependencies to be useful as static PDF document. For that I want to use an interactive graph viewer, where I can dynamically select a main vertex (or two, restricting the displayed connections), temporarily hide vertices/edges to make the graph more accessible, zoom in/out, etc.

What are my open-source alternative for such an interactive tool?

Comment: Here's a [long list](http://www.mkbergman.com/414/large-scale-rdf-graph-visualization-tools/).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [the long list](http://www.mkbergman.com/414/large-scale-rdf-graph-visualization-tools/) (from [Paul Sweatte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113772/paul-sweatte)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163238/interactive-alternative-to-dot#comment26712089_18163238)):

> **[InfoVis Toolkit](http://ivtk.sourceforge.net/)** – The InfoVis Toolkit is an interactive graphics toolkit written in
> Java to ease the development of Information Visualization applications
> and components

> **[Prefuse](http://kneecap.ist.berkeley.edu/)** – Prefuse is a user interface toolkit for building highly
> interactive visualizations of structured and unstructured data. This
> includes any form of data that can be represented as a set of entities
> (or nodes) possibly connected by any number of relations (or edges).
> Examples of data supported by prefuse include hierarchies
> (organization charts, taxonomies, file systems), networks (computer
> networks, social networks, web site linkage) and even non-connected
> collections of data (timelines, scatterplots). See also Jeff Heer, the
> author of Prefuse (http://jheer.org/)

> **[Treebolic](http://treebolic.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)** - Treebolic is a Java component (widget) whose purpose is to provide a
> hyperbolic rendering of hierarchical data. A tree is rendered with
> nodes and edges but display space is subject to a particular curvature
> (hence the name) : more space is allocated to the focus node while the
> parent and children, still in the immediate visual context, appear
> slightly smaller. The grandparents and grandchildren are still visible
> but come out even smaller. As we move away from the focus node, less
> display space is allotted to the nodes, which gradually disappear
> towards the disk’s border, as though the whole hierarchy were seen
> through a fisheye lens. Wrapped as a Java applet, the Treebolic widget
> can be embedded in a web page. Nodes may then contain hypertext links
> and the browser to other web pages. The tree is dynamic (animation
> brings the focus node to the center) and responds to user interaction.

> **[Walrus](http://www.caida.org/tools/visualization/walrus/)** – Walrus is a tool for interactively visualizing large directed
> graphs in three-dimensional space. By employing a fisheye-like
> distortion, it provides a display that simultaneously shows local
> detail and the global context. It is technically possible to display
> graphs containing a million nodes or more, but visual clutter,
> occlusion, and other factors can diminish the effectiveness of Walrus
> as the number of nodes, or the degree of their connectivity,
> increases. Thus, in practice, Walrus is best suited to visualizing
> moderately sized graphs that are nearly trees. A graph with a few
> hundred thousand nodes and only a slightly greater number of links is
> likely to best target size